# Trouble Saving to List/Dict in C# App when using Classes/Constructors to Hold the Data

Tags: c#, class, validation, variables, constructor

This is my 2nd question asked to StackOverflow so hopefully I learned how to provide enough information :)

I am creating a c# console app that stores any amount of User Defined Robots then assigns tasks to the robots and displays the leaderboard/total time these robots take to perform tasks on the console.

I would like the user to enter a robot name then select a type of robot using a numerical key defined in a class named BotType. There is also a class for Robot which I want to hold botName, botType (defined by the BotType class, hopefully) and timeElapsed. Then it will call a AssignBotTask method with a CompleteTask method randonly assigning the task then storing the amount of time taken and totaling etc.

The way I am setting up the CreateRobot method is:
I would like user to enter robot name. (botName)
Enter robot type. (botType)
Create a robot using the Robot class.
AssignBotTask(); ...
Display each user defined robot etc...

I am having trouble saving the user defined robots into the application using the Robot class/constructor. My thoughts were to save this info in a List or Dictionary so I can add/delete/view robots further in the app. While trying this, I can't figure out how to add the user defined values into the Constructor Robot then saving them as Robots. All my research points to fixed variables (Robot) where the users are not defining them.

**How can I store user defined botName and botType into the Robot class/constructor like so?**
robotList is being used to know the user definitions exist but botList1 is trying to save them as Robot but I am returning the following in debug watch:
{Name="Robot" FullName="BotOMat.Robot"}
But I'd like the user definitions to show up here.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, int> robotList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public static List<Robot> botList = new List<Robot>();
    public static List<Type> botList1 = new List<Type>();
    
    public static void createRobot()
    {
        //Get robot name, add to list saving multiple names.
        Console.WriteLine("Enter robot name:");
        string botName = Console.ReadLine();
    
        //Get robot type
        Console.WriteLine("Enter robot type: (number)");
        int botType = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if(botType < 1 || botType > 6)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter number 1-6.");
            botType= 0;
        }
    
        //Add robot to the class storing robot information.
        if(botType > 1 || botType < 6)
        {
            new Robot(botName, botType);
    
            robotList.Add(botName, botType);
            botList1.Add(typeof(Robot));
    
    
            //Robot.AssignBotTask();
            //Leaderboard.checkUserTime(robot);
            //Leaderboard.checkUserProductivity(robot);
        }
        else
        {
            MainMenu();
        }
        
    }
    
    private static void displayRobots()
    {
        foreach(Robot aRobot in botList1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(aRobot);
        }
        
    }
    
public class Robot
    {
        //Store robot name
        public string botName;

        //Store robot type
        public int botType;

        //Store time to complete task
        private int timeElapsed;

        //Task completed by robot
        public Dictionary<int, BotTask> completeBotTask;

        public Robot(string BotName, int BotType)
        {
            BotName = botName;
            BotType = botType;
            timeElapsed = 0;
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like you are missing something here… `new Robot(botName, botType);` ? … the code “creates” a new `Robot` object however it never “assigns” it to anything. Something like… `Robot newRobot = new Robot(botName, botType);` …and to add it to the list… `botList1.Add(newRobot);` OR `botList1.Add(new Robot(botName, botType));`

Comment: Also, the `Robot` constructor is not doing what you think it is doing. `BotName = botName;` and `BotType = botType;` ? … this is backwards. i.e… `botName = BotName;` and `botType = BotType;`.

Answer (score 0):

(If I understood what you trying to do correctly)

you only need this one:

```
public static List<Robot> botList = new List<Robot>();
```

and your iteration to display robots should use it as follows:

```
private static void displayRobots()
{
   foreach(Robot aRobot in botList)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(aRobot.botName + " type:" aRobot.botType);
   }        
}
```